# cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugin not working on Windows 10 sencha touch store app

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, windows-10-universal

I have been using filetransfer plugin in our hybrid html app and it supports both widows 8.1 and ios and android but I also need it to work in Windows 10 store app. It seems like it cannot download file in windows 10 please suggest some alternative plugin to download files from server or if we got this work in windows 10

sample code below

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI("some_url.com");
var fileName = "localpathofwindows"
fileTransfer.download(uri, fileName,
function(entry) {
console.log("file download success");
},
function(error) {
console.log("file download failure");
},
false, {
headers: {
"Authorization": auth,
"action": "getFiles"
}
});
```

Comment: Is fileTransfer.download() giving you a callback?

Comment: cordova filetransfer is deprecated as you can use file dowload directly: https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all it is not a problem with apache cordova or visual studio. It's windows 10 network settings. All I had to do is reset network settings of my windows 10 computer.

Search "Settings".

Click on "Network and Ethernet"

Click on "Status"

Click on "Network Reset" .

Restart your computer.

Comment: Found a new reason for this problem. Every time I had this issue I had open season in fiddler software. Once I closed fiddler the issue was gone.